# Where is Rico sitting in the menu screen?

Tags: just-cause-3

I believe I was at the location after finishing the final mission. I didn't think to look on the map where I was (or if I did, I have since forgotten), and it's bugged me ever since that I can't find the place again. He's on a beach with a hillside to his left, and is looking at the smoke of something.

Answer (score 6):

You are talking about the same place like the one in the title screen. I found the location on imgur like a month ago and coordinate are N 40 51.122 E 5 29.925
[image]